# glassfish 3.1.2 - ResultSetWrapper40 cannot be cast to oracle.jdbc.OracleResultSet

Tags: oracle, jdbc, glassfish, connection-pooling, resultset

I recently migrate from glassfish 3.1.1 to 3.1.2 and I got the following error

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.gjc.spi.jdbc40.ResultSetWrapper40 cannot be cast to oracle.jdbc.OracleResultSet
```

at the line

```
oracle.sql.BLOB bfile = ((OracleResultSet) rs).getBLOB("filename");
```

in the following routine:

```
public void fetchPdf(int matricola, String anno, String mese, String tableType, ServletOutputStream os) {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
    String query = "SELECT filename FROM "
                + tableType + " where matricola = " + matricola
                + " and anno = " + anno
                + ((tableType.equals("gf_blob_ced") || tableType.equals("gf_blob_car")) ? " and mese = " + mese : "");

    InputStream ins = null;

    //--------
    try {

        Connection conn = dataSource.getConnection();
        //Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connection, "glassfish", pwd);
        java.sql.Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
        if (rs.next()) {
            logger.info("select ok " + query);
            oracle.sql.BLOB bfile = ((OracleResultSet) rs).getBLOB("filename");

            ins = bfile.getBinaryStream();

            int length;
            while ((length = (ins.read(buffer))) >= 0) {
                os.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }

            ins.close();

        } else {
            logger.info("select Nok " + query);
        }
        rs.close();
        stmt.close();
        //conn.close();

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        logger.warn("blob file non raggiungibile: "+query);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        logger.warn("connessione non riuscita");
    }
}
```

I'm using the glassfish connection pool

```
@Resource(name = "jdbc/ape4")
    private DataSource dataSource;
```

and the jdbc/ape4 resource belongs to an oracle connection pool with the following param

```
NetworkProtocol tcp
LoginTimeout    0
PortNumber  1521
Password    xxxxxxxx
MaxStatements   0
ServerName  server
DataSourceName  OracleConnectionPoolDataSource
URL jdbc:oracle:thin:@server:1521:APE4
User    glassfish
ExplicitCachingEnabled  false
DatabaseName    APE4
ImplicitCachingEnabled  false
```

The oracle driver is ojdbc6.jar, oracle DB is 10g.

Could anyone help me what is happening? On Glassfish 3.1.1 it was working fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need for not using standard JDBC api in this code. You are not using any Oracle-specific functionality so `rs.getBlob("filename").getBinaryStream()` will work just as well.

If you insist on keeping this, turn off [JDBC Object wrapping](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2418/giyde.html) option for your datasource.

Comment: Thanks. I turned off JDBC Object wrapping but also I had to chenge the DataSourceName from OracleConnectionPoolDataSource to OracleDataSource and the resource type to javax.sql.DataSource instead of javax.sql.ConnectionPoolDataSource. Are there any consequences using a different resource type?

Comment: @maxqua72 Why not just use the JDBC standard methods. Nothing in your code requires you to use the Oracle specific methods.

Comment: Yes, I will but I would like to understand either. Your answer fixed my problem but I've still holes to fill in my knowledge about this topic. Thanks.

Comment: @maxqua72 changing `ConnectionPoolDatasource` to `Datasource` was needed as former does not have method `getConnection()` only `getPooledConnection()`. OracleConnectionPoolDatasource implements both interfaces.